# Nested composite foreign keys as ID in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

We are developing an online store in Symfony 5 and Doctrine 2 where multiple customers (called participants in this case) can participate in the same order item and share the cost. The following simplified class diagram demonstrates the domain model:

[image: Class diagram]

The pure object model works fine in unit tests, but you obviously need to persist the data to a database, which is why we need to introduce IDs.

`Order`, `Product` and `Participant` are entities with their own ID. In an ideal world, `OrderItem` and `OrderItemParticipation` would not need their own ID but be identified by the related entities they belong to, meaning their ID would be a composite foreign key.

So, an `OrderItem` would by identified by the composite key of `Order.id` and `Product.id`, which is pretty much exactly the same as given in this example from the Doctrine 2 documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata.

Since `OrderItemParticipation` relates to `OrderItem`, which uses a composite key itself, it would need to use a nested composite key consisting of `Order.id`, `Product.id` and `Participant.id`.

Unfortunately, Doctrine 2 doesn't seem to be able to work with nested composite keys as ID. I get this error

> Column name `id` referenced for relation from
> App\Entity\OrderItemParticipation towards App\Entity\OrderItem does
> not exist.

when I try to generate a migration with the following mapping:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class OrderItem {
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Order::class, inversedBy="items")
     */
    private Order $order;
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Product::class)
     */
    private Product $product;
    // ...
}

/** @ORM\Entity */
class OrderItemParticipation {
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=OrderItem::class, inversedBy="participations")
     */
    private OrderItem $orderItem;
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Participant::class)
     */
    private Participant $participant;
    // ...
}
```

So it seems that Doctrine is fine with my ID mapping in `OrderItem`, but it struggles when it gets to `OrderItemParticipation`. Is there a way to make Doctrine work with the given domain model? Is it maybe just an issue with the auto-generation of the migration, so if I had already manually set up the database, Doctrine might work with the given mapping? Or is the nested composite key ID approach too complicated for Doctrine?

Comment: I don't work with Doctrine, so I don't understand your mapping code, which seems to do nothing, but I would think if you simply introduce an `+id` in `OrderItem` itself your problems would be solved. `OrderItemParticipation` can then refer to that id. I probably don't get this at all, sorry.

Comment: I personally have never gotten composite keys to work to my satisfaction let alone nested ones.  I'd say it was time to acknowledge that we don't live in an ideal world and just use explicit ids.  I know it can be a bit annoying to add a column that, from a database point of view, is not needed but sometimes it's best to keep things simple.

Comment: My perfectionism for clean and beautiful code makes me try to accomplish things in the ideal way first... but I guess I will have to go for the explicit ID... @KIKOSoftware introducing an explicit ID is what I was trying to avoid, because the identity of an `OrderItem` is implicitly given by the identity of the other entities that `OrderItem` is referring to. But as I said, it's probably the easiest way

Comment: Yes, it probably is the easiest way. I've become lazy, I simply use an auto-increase ID at the beginning of every table, regardless of what it contains. However, I do often use composite keys, they can speed up certain queries significantly.